# Integrar TinyMCE en Laravel +10

Tags: laravel, tinymce

Soy novato en Laravel y estoy intentando integrar TinyMCE en mi proyecto Laravel.
Intento hacer la instalación siguiendo la guía que tienen en su web [tinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/laravel/laravel-composer-install/) pero en el paso 5:

> Add a Laravel Mix task to copy TinyMCE to the public files when Mix is
> run, such as: File: webpack.mix.js
> mix.copyDirectory('vendor/tinymce/tinymce', 'public/js/tinymce');

Me da errores que no consigo solucionar al ejecutar el comando `npx mix`

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module L:\Dev\admin-panel\webpack.mix.js from L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js not supported.
webpack.mix.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename webpack.mix.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in L:\Dev\admin-panel\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at module.exports (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:11:5)
    at loadConfigByPath (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1439:37)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async WebpackCLI.loadConfig (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1454:35)
    at async WebpackCLI.createCompiler (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1785:22)
    at async WebpackCLI.runWebpack (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1890:20)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:912:21)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (L:\Dev\admin-panel\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1372:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

El fichero `webpack.mix.js` lo he tenido que crear a mano en mi root del proyecto y tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.copyDirectory('vendor/tinymce/tinymce', 'public/js/tinymce');
```

¿Qué error puedo estar haciendo?